# I can't figure out what is wrong with my regex?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

below is is the code in question:

```
ID = null;
Table = null;

Match CMD = Regex.Match(CommandString, @"create update command for (^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$) Where_ID_=_(^[0-9]+$)"); //create update command for MARKSWhere_ID_=_11

if (CMD.Success)
{
    Table = CMD.Groups[1].Value;
    ID = CMD.Groups[2].Value;

    return true;
}
```

this is returning false every time when

```
CommandString = "create update command for MARKS Where_ID_=_5"
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regular expression you used, `^` denote the beginning of the input string, and `$` denotes the end of the input string.

Removing `^` and `$` from the regular expression will give you what you want.

Comment: yes... the begining of that substring and the end of that substring that is enclosed in brackets

Answer (score 0):

1. [A-Za-z0-9]{0,10} will allow only 10 alphabet form a to z A to Z and from 0 to 9
2. Soo its good habit to put fix number of alphabet match by regex.